# React child : If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have the following error when trying to use. map in an array

> React child (found: object with keys {name, redirectTo}). If you meant
>   to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

```
 const MenuTags = [
    { name: 'home', redirectTo: '/' },
    { name: 'about', redirectTo: '../about' },
    { name: 'not dropdown', redirectTo: '../dashboard' },
    { name: 'not dropdown', redirectTo: '../dashboard/about' },
  ];

 {MenuTags.map(item => (
        <NavLi
          key={item.name}
          redirectTo={item.redirectTo}
          onClick={() => onUpdateVisibility(item)}
        >
          {item}
        </NavLi>
      ))}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `{item}` to `{item.name}` like this

```
 const MenuTags = [
     { name: 'home', redirectTo: '/' },
     { name: 'about', redirectTo: '../about' },
     { name: 'not dropdown', redirectTo: '../dashboard' },
     { name: 'not dropdown', redirectTo: '../dashboard/about' },
];

{MenuTags.map(item => (
    <NavLi
        key={item.name}
        redirectTo={item.redirectTo}
        onClick={() => onUpdateVisibility(item)}
    >

      **** Change here ****
      {item.name}
    </NavLi>
))}
```